# Mincer-Zarnowitz test with cointegrated time series

Tags: hypothesis-testing, forecasting, stationarity, model-evaluation, cointegration

The Mincer-Zarnowitz test of forecast optimality regresses forecast errors $e_{t+h|t}$ on the forecasts $\hat y_{t+h|t}$,
$$
e_{t+h|t} = \gamma_0 + \gamma_1\hat y_{t+h|t} + u_t \tag{1}
$$
or in another formulation, realized values $y_{t+h}$ on the forecasts $\hat y_{t+h|t}$,
$$
y_{t+h} = \delta_0 + \delta_1\hat y_{t+h|t} + u_t \tag{2}
$$
(See p. 337 of Diebold ["Forecasting in Economics, Business, Finance and Beyond"](https://www.sas.upenn.edu/%7Efdiebold/Teaching221/Forecasting.pdf) (2017) for details.)

Suppose the realized values $y_t$ and the forecasts $y_{t+h|t}$ are each integrated. Further suppose they are cointegrated with a cointegrating vector $\beta=(1,-\beta_1)^\top$. (For simplicity, we could assume $\beta_1=1$.) Unless $\gamma_1=\beta_1-1$ or equivalently, $\delta_1=\beta_1$, we get an unbalanced regression.

How does this affect the distribution of the test statistic under $H_0\colon\ \delta_0=0,\ \delta_1=1$, or equivalently $H_0\colon\ \gamma_0=0,\ \gamma_1=0$? Can "naive" critical values be used under such circumstances? If not, is there a way around the problem?

Comment: Somewhat related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/145327

Answer (score 3):

There is a way around this problem. Note that given $y_t$, there is no difference between forecasting $y_{t+h}$ and $\Delta_h y_{t+h}:=y_{t+h}-y_{t}$.

- From $\hat y_{t+h|t}$ and $y_t$ we can obtain $\widehat{ \Delta_h y}_{t+h|t}$ as $\widehat{ \Delta_h y}_{t+h|t}=\hat y_{t+h|t}-y_t$.
- From $\widehat{ \Delta_h y}_{t+h|t}$ and $y_t$ we can obtain $\hat y_{t+h|t}$ as $\hat y_{t+h|t}=\widehat{ \Delta_h y}_{t+h|t}+y_{t}$.

Therefore, we can work with the pair of I(0) processes $(e_{t+h|t},\widehat{ \Delta_h y}_{t+h|t})$ in place of the mixed I(0), I(1) pair $(e_{t+h|t},\hat y_{t+h|t})$, and then the Mincer-Zarnowitz test is unproblematic.